# Parse p nodes text including sibling nodes until the next p node

Tags: python, xml, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Weird title, I know. I am trying to parse an XML document which is kind of structured in paragraph. However, sometimes there are additional nodes which should be inside a paragraph but simply aren't.

What I need is to find each paragraph but also select everything until the next paragraph up to a "termination" node e.g. which is here the `title` node.

Here's an example:

```xml
<p typ="ct">(1) This is rule one</p>
<ol>
  <li>With some text</li>
  <li>that I want to parse</li>
</ol>
<p typ="ct">(2) And here is rule two</p>
<p typ="ct">(3) and rule three</p>
<title>Another section</title>
```

My desired output would be something like:

```py
[
  "(1) This is rule one\nWith some text\nthat I want to parse", 
  "(2) And here is rule two", 
  "(3) and rule three"
]
```

If know I can select each paragraph using something like `soup.select("p[typ=ct]")` or `soup.find_all("p", attr=dict(typ="ct")` but it's those parts inbetween which I am not sure how to parse in a soupy way.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example structure you could use `find_next_sibling('ol')` to select the direct sibling of the `<p>`s as a generic approach:

```
['\n'.join([e.text, o.get_text('\n',strip=True) if (o:=e.find_next('ol')) else '']) for e in soup.select('p[typ="ct"]')]
```

**Note:** *walrus operator needs `Python 3.8` or higher*

##### Example

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
xml = '''
<p typ="ct">(1) This is rule one</p>
<ol>
  <li>With some text</li>
  <li>that I want to parse</li>
</ol>
<p typ="ct">(2) And here is rule two</p>
<p typ="ct">(3) and rule three</p>
<title>Another section</title>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml)

['\n'.join([e.text, o.get_text('\n',strip=True) if (o:=e.find_next('ol')) else '']) for e in soup.select('p[typ="ct"]')]
```

##### Output

```
['(1) This is rule one\nWith some text\nthat I want to parse',
 '(2) And here is rule two\n',
 '(3) and rule three\n']
```

---

Or maybe closer to the point with the "terminator" iterate over the `<title>`s:

```
for e in soup.select('title'):
    s = []
    for tag in e.find_next_siblings():
        if tag.name != 'title':
            if tag.name != 'p':
                s[-1]= s[-1]+'\n'+tag.get_text('\n', strip=True)
            else:
                s.append(tag.get_text(strip=True))
        else:
            break
    data.append(s)
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml = '''
<title>A section</title>
<p typ="ct">(1) This is rule one</p>
<ol>
  <li>With some text</li>
  <li>that I want to parse</li>
</ol>
<p typ="ct">(2) And here is rule two</p>
<p typ="ct">(3) and rule three</p>
<title>B section</title>
<p typ="ct">(1) This is rule one</p>
<p typ="ct">(2) And here is rule two</p>
<ol>
  <li>With some text</li>
  <li>that I want to parse</li>
</ol>
<p typ="ct">(3) and rule three</p>
<title>C section</title>
<p typ="ct">(1) This is rule one</p>
<p typ="ct">(2) And here is rule two</p>
<p typ="ct">(3) and rule three</p>
<ol>
  <li>With some text</li>
  <li>that I want to parse</li>
</ol>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, 'html.parser')

data = []

for e in soup.select('title'):
    s = []
    for tag in e.find_next_siblings():
        if tag.name != 'title':
            if tag.name != 'p':
                s[-1]= s[-1]+'\n'+tag.get_text('\n', strip=True)
            else:
                s.append(tag.get_text(strip=True))
        else:
            break
    data.append(s)

data
```

##### Output

```
[['(1) This is rule one\nWith some text\nthat I want to parse',
  '(2) And here is rule two',
  '(3) and rule three'],
 ['(1) This is rule one',
  '(2) And here is rule two\nWith some text\nthat I want to parse',
  '(3) and rule three'],
 ['(1) This is rule one',
  '(2) And here is rule two',
  '(3) and rule three\nWith some text\nthat I want to parse']]
```